# cmap macros not working as expected

Tags: key-bindings, macro, cmdline

I have been trying to make a macro to allow me to check in/out files via the vim command line. Currently what I have which "sort of" works is this:

```
nmap :checkout :! cleartool checkout -nc %
```

As you can see there is a bit of redundancy using nmap.  I was under the impression that cmap created a macro which only functioned in the command line, so I thought I could do something like this:

```
cmap checkout ! cleartool checkout -nc %
```

however this seems to be creating a recursive loop which crashes vim.  Is there something I'm missing?  would I want to use a different map or is my syntax wrong?

Comment: The crash is because you need cnoremap. But I agree with the answer and would use a command instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you want to create a new command. Like this:

```
:command Checkout :!cleartool checkout -nc %
```

This allows you to run `cleartool checkout` from Vim with the command `:Checkout`.

Note: User defined commands must start with a upper case letter.

Comment: interesting.  I wasn't aware of the need for the "command" keyword.